# Java counting objects of class with different fields

Tags: java, object, counting

I have a simple class with one field `size`. Im creating objects of `size = 2` and `size = 3` etc.. I want to count every object of every size. something like `private static int counter = 0` incremented in constructor, but I need many counters ( like an array? ), for every kind of object. How do I do it?

Comment: can you add you code? is not so clear without the full code

Comment: Learn how to use a Map. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Map* to store the counter of each size could be useful

```
public class MyObject {
    private static Map<Integer, Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();

    private int size;

    public MyObject(int size) {
        this.size = size;
        Integer sizeCounter = counters.get(size);
        if (sizeCounter == null) {
            sizeCounter = 0;
        }
        counters.put(size, ++sizeCounter);
    }

    public static Integer getSizeCounter(Integer size) {
        Integer sizeCounter = counters.get(size);
        if (sizeCounter == null) {
            sizeCounter = 0;
        }
        return sizeCounter;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyObject mo11 = new MyObject(1);
        MyObject mo12 = new MyObject(1);
        MyObject mo13 = new MyObject(1);
        MyObject mo2 = new MyObject(2);
        MyObject mo3 = new MyObject(3);
        System.out.println(MyObject.getSizeCounter(1)); // prints 3
        System.out.println(MyObject.getSizeCounter(2)); // prints 1
        System.out.println(MyObject.getSizeCounter(3)); // prints 1
        System.out.println(MyObject.getSizeCounter(4)); // prints 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, but how do I read a value of counter for object of specified size?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you need to read the counters for all the sizes then add a new getter which returns the *counters* map and then iterate over the map

Comment: Map is a very new thing to me, how do I call `getSizeCounter()` method? I need it to control a limit of object of specified size that can be created.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I've made `getSizeCounter()` method static so it can be accessed without the need of an instance of MyObject class.

Comment: It worked, thanks for your time. I will finish my project tomorrow, hope so there won't be any more troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static hashmap, like so,

```
    public class MyObject {
    private static HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    private int size;

    public MyObject(int size) {
       this.size = size;
       if(map.containsKey((Integer)size)){
           Integer sizeCount = map.get((Integer)size);
           map.put((Integer)size, sizeCount+1);
       }else{
          map.put((Integer)size, 1);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use `Map<YourObject, Integer>` which you will increment values based on key. And for this YourObject which has a size should override `equals` and `hasCode` methods. Your size field should be used in this methods to compare ans return.

Answer (score -2):

A static `Map` in your class can be used to accumulate the size for each object:

```
public class MyObject {
    private static Map<Long, Long> counter = new HashMap<>();

    private long size;

    public MyObject(long size) {
        this.size = size;
        if(!counter.containsKey(1l))
        {
            counter.put(size, 1l);
        }
        else
        {
            counter.put(size, counter.get(size) + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

If you have a setter for the `size` field you'll want to handle the `counter` update there as well.

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. He/she wants a histogram: the number of objects per size: 2 objects of size 3, 7 objects of size 5, for example.

Comment: Wrong answer! - in this case `counter` is a sum of all ever created objects' sizes.

Comment: Yikes, the intent wasn't clear to me from the post. Updated answer.